# I've been running a standalone container I started with 'docker run'. How do I now include that in a Docker Compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been running Prometheus in a container for about a week collecting metrics on some of my servers. I originally started the container with a 'docker run' from the shell. Now I want to add prom/alertmanager for alerting and realise it's best to manage this with a docker-compose file.

I've written the docker-compose.yml and it's all working great, but the problem is it treats the Prometheus container in the Compose file as a new container, where I want to keep using the existing container to preserve the metrics I've been collecting for the last week.

```
ERROR: for prometheus  Cannot create container for service prometheus: Conflict. The container name "/prometheus" is already in use by container "409041cc80aa7eff00202baf1adda5ea07d3d0ad06ed2af7baf6cf1f8ac76511". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

Is there any way I can keep using the existing container as part of my docker-compose.yml? If I have to lose it all, it's not a huge deal, but I figure there's probably a way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you have a volume mounted to your existing docker Prometheus container  to persist the data? If so, just mount that same volume in your docker compose based container. If you did not mount a volume in the original container, all the data will go away when you stop that container and you ll have to copy the data out out the container before you stop it (docker cp). Then you can place that data in a folder in your host and mounted to the correct directory in the image so that the new container can see it. Never tried this with Prometheus, but it should work

Comment: I think you need to take a look at docker cp command and volumes. Copy your metrics from your container to the host with docker cp and then connect that folder from host to new container with docker volumes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will always do that since when you use a docker-compose file and recreate it, it's pointing to that docker-compose file configuration. Whenever you are just running a docker run and doing it again, it will tell you it's already in use cause it doesn't know you're pointing to that same configuration and will treat it as a completely new container. Same counts for run -> docker-compose. It would indeed be best to copy things over like ^ said.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I see I need to expand my learning about Docker into how volume mounting works. I have previously not been doing that. I'm going to write off the old container and start with a mounted volume in my compose file.